# add quotation mark to a text file powershell

Tags: powershell, quotation-marks

I need to add the quotation mark to a text file that contains 500 lines text.
The format is inconsistent. It has dashes, dots, numbers, and letters. For example

> 1527c705-839a-4832-9118-54d4Bd6a0c89
>
> 16575getfireshot.com.FireShotCaptureWebpageScreens
>
> 3EA2211E.GestetnerDriverUtility

I have tried to code this

```
$Flist = Get-Content "$home\$user\appfiles\out.txt"
$Flist | %{$_ -replace '^(.*?)', '"'}
```

I got the result which only added to the beginning of a line.

```
"Microsoft.WinJS.2.0
```

The expected result should be

**"Microsoft.WinJS.2.0"**

> How to add quotation-mark to the end of each line as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no strict need to use a regex (regular expression) in your case (requires PSv4+):

```
(Get-Content $home\$user\appfiles\out.txt).ForEach({ '"{0}"' -f $_ })
```

- [Array method `.ForEach()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays#foreach) processes each input line via the script block (`{ ... }`) passed to it.
- `'"{0}"' -f $_` effectively encloses each input line (`$_`) in double quotes, via [`-f`, the string-format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#format-operator--f).

---

If you did want to use a regex:

```
(Get-Content $home\$user\appfiles\out.txt) -replace '^|$', '"'
```

Regex `^|$` matches both the start (`^`) and the end (`$`) of the input string and replaces both with a `"` char., effectively enclosing the input string in double quotes.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `^(.*?)`

just matches the very *start* of the string (`^`), and nothing else, given that `.*?` - due to using the *non-greedy* duplication symbol `?` - matches nothing else.

Therefore, replacing what matched with `"` only placed a `"` at the *start* of the input string, not also at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to match both:

- The beginning of the line `^(.*?)`
- OR `|`
- The End of the line `$`

I.e. `^(.*?)|$`

```
$Flist = Get-Content "$home\$user\appfiles\out.txt"
$Flist | %{$_ -replace '^(.*?)|$', '"'}
```